# How to modify the radius of the curve based on the proximity with several instanced points along its path ? (geometry nodes)

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, procedural

Okay so; I'm pretty sure this question hasn't been answered here, but I might be wrong and just not know how to formulate my problem. If it is the case, I am extremely sorry.

I am rather new to geometry nodes, and am trying myself at procedural modeling after learning procedural shading. Here, I am trying to create a group of neatly arranged cables (just like what you could find in a server room). My approach was to use a curve and create a profile for it using this node group:

[image: image of a node group creating a circle and placing smaller circles at each point of the circle, then applying the resulting shape as a profile.]

Here is the result of that group:

[image: Result of the node group on a random curve]

Now, my goal is to add zip ties (that I will model independently and place along points, which shouldn't be a problem in theory). But before that, I want to slightly reduce the radius of the curve around the points where the zip ties will be, in order for it to look slightly more organic, and that is where my problem is. This is my current setup:

[image: Current node setup]

So far, I have tried plugging both capture attribute nodes into a vector math node set to "distance", but it only gave the distance of the curve to the averaged positions of the points. I want to compute the distance of each point of the curve to the nearest instanced point, but I do not know how to do this... My goal is then to plug this in a math node set to "less than", and then a switch node with both values of my radius and plug it into the radius of the Set curve radius node. Any idea on how to proceed?

EDIT: I have tried to add a blend file containing the relevant mesh and nodes, if this is the wrong way to do it, I'll edit again! [link for the download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11hEHqqT1yB1IN24zOevTZy9n09Lgm3ai/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you will attract way more people if you provide a blend file...

Comment: Edit made ! I am sorry, this is my first time posting here, and the posts I've seen so far never inclued a blend file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to complete the range of wonderful solutions, here is another suggestion:

You could also just directly affect the curve radius, saving a lot of nodes:

[image]

Instead of changing the mesh afterwards here, I use the node `Geometry Proximity` even before converting it to a mesh. This allows me to specify the desired value as the curve radius, which is then taken into account when applying `Curve to Mesh`.

Answer (score 3):

if you add this to your GN node tree:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is how I approached this:

[image]

Or for [kiełbasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kielbasa)

[image]

[image]

Comment: All these answers were wonderful, and taught me a bit more about geometry nodes. I chose to use the simpler version for this application, but will definitely use the others for other parts of my project! Thank you all!!